# SQL Syntax Error Near ')'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm implementing a C# desktop application that uses SQL server database.

I have this code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC;Initial Catalog=FRAT_DB;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("select MAX(PhotoID) from Photo", cn);
cn.Open();
SqlDataReader MaxID_Selector = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
double maxID = 0;
while (MaxID_Selector.Read())
{
    if (MaxID_Selector[0].ToString().Trim() != "") 
    {
        maxID = Convert.ToInt64(MaxID_Selector[0].ToString());
    }
}
maxID = maxID + 1;
cn.Close();

SqlCommand cmdb = new SqlCommand(@"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @personID) BEGIN  UPDATE Person SET PersonID = @PersonID, Name= @Name, Age= @Age,P_Group=@P_Group, Email= @Email END ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO Person(PersonID,Name,Age,P_Group,Email) values(@PersonID,@Name,@Age,@P_Group,@Email)", cn);

cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", personID);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", textBox2.Text);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_Group", textBox6.Text);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox5.Text);`
```

When I run the program and try to save the information, I get this error message: `Syntax Error Near ')'`

Any solutions?

Comment: do you get the error in sql query?

Comment: Try copying the text you're running in the command and run it in Management Studio to separate TSQL issues from C# issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're missing an "End" after the insert. This is untested, but try below:

```
SqlCommand cmdb = new SqlCommand(@"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @personID) 
                                       BEGIN  
                                           UPDATE Person SET PersonID = @PersonID, Name= @Name, Age= @Age,P_Group=@P_Group, Email= @Email 
                                       END 
                                   ELSE 
                                       BEGIN 
                                           INSERT INTO Person(PersonID,Name,Age,P_Group,Email) values(@PersonID,@Name,@Age,@P_Group,@Email) 
                                       END ", cn
                                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed "End" after the insert, in second insert statement,  try below:

```
SqlCommand cmdb = new SqlCommand(@"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @personID) BEGIN UPDATE Person SET PersonID = @PersonID, Name= @Name, Age= @Age,P_Group=@P_Group, Email= @Email END ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO Person(PersonID,Name,Age,P_Group,Email) values(@PersonID,@Name,@Age,@P_Group,@Email) END ", cn);
```